# Kibana two different DSL Queries behaving as OR

Tags: kibana, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm trying to create two Queries that appear as blue button on Visualizer that I want to apply both as if they are a OR [image: see below]. So in this case I can filter my logs by INFO or ERROR or BOTH AT THE SAME TIME. If I enable one or the other alone they work as expected but if I enable both it's like the final query is a INFO AND ERROR when what I want is INFO OR ERROR. Both of the queries are similar, one with ERROR the other with INFO

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "message": "INFO"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I used both *filter* and *should*.

I do saw the Inspect but I can't understand it.....

Any idea if this is possible at all?

Thanks.

**EDITED** for clarification after 1st reply:

What I need is 2 different, separated queries (one with *"status": "info"* and the other *"status": "error"*, because **I want to attach them to those blue buttons that appear when you click "Add a filter"**. So I end up with **2 blue buttons**, **ERROR** and **INFO**, in a way that when they are both enabled it will show both. At the moment they work individually but when I enable both I think it behaves like ERROR AND INFO and no line have both, so what I want is some kind of **ERROR OR INFO** so it will display both. Any idea?

**EDIT 2:**
From my last comment below, looking at the Inspect with two scripts each one in its own button, it shows

**Inspect**

```
 "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [   <--- my scripts below get wrapped in this MUST
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "message": "INFO"
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "message": "ERROR"
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        },
        ...
```

and the scripts I have in the two buttons

**INFO**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "message": "INFO"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "message": "ERROR"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

So if there is no way to change the way Kimunda wraps the scripts I guess I'm screwed...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
You can use `is one of` it will be **OR** query.

[image]

You can use the should query.

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test_should", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "status" : "info" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test_should", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "status" : "error" }

GET test_should/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "status": "info"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "status": "error"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but what I need is 2 different, separated queries (one with "status": "info" and the other "status": "error", because I want to attach them to those blue buttons that appear when you click "Add a filter". So I end up with 2 blue buttons, ERROR and INFO, in a way that when they are both enabled it will show both. At the moment they work individually but when I enable both I thins it behaves like ERROR AND INFO and no line have both, so what I want is some kind of ERROR OR INFO so it will display both. Any idea?

Comment: I've got your point and my answer is updated please check

Comment: I'm afraid not, it works if the script is in only one button, but I need to have the ERROR and the INFO on two separate buttons. And now from what I see from the Inspect (thanks for the tip) I think it's probably impossible because Kibana wraps everything in a MUST!!! I'll update my question to show it...